# How to create a very large sparse identity matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to create a 75000*75000 identity matrix in Matlab with the code:

```
sparse(eye(75000))
```

and I get the following error:

```
Requested 75000x75000 (41.9GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays
greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array
size limit or preference panel for more information.
```

I know the reason for the error, but but how can I create such a sparse matrix in Matlab?

Comment: [`speye`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/speye.html) is the [third result](http://www.mathworks.com/help/search.html?qdoc=sparse+identity&submitsearch=) from the documentation...

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer if you provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sparse(eye(75000));
```

Requires `eye(75000)` be stored in memory. You want to use [`speye`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/speye.html) to avoid the intermediate step:

```
speye(75000);
```

I'd also recommend reading the documentation for [Sparse Matrix Creation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrix-creation.html).